# Rails2.3.8 Resque.enqueue doesn't forward the job to background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am trying to set up Resque. I have following in my environment.rb

```
config.gem "redis", :version =>  "3.0"
config.gem "redis-namespace", :version => "1.2.1", :lib => "redis/namespace"
config.gem "resque", :version => "1.23.0"
```

I followed the [asciicast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque?view=asciicast) upto before starting `resque-web`. In my controller I have

```
Resque.enqueue(SnippetHighlighter, @snippet.id)
```

like in the example given in the asciicast. However, my process isn't forwarded to the background but to the rails server. According to the asciicast, I should not get error in the `rails server` but in the resque.

Also when I start my resque-web, I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby1.8/net/http.rb:560: in 'initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or 
service not known(SocketError)
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Do you have your SnippetHighligher class setup for Resque?

Comment: do I need to do anything more as specified in the asciicast? I set up `resque.rake` and `redis.yml` as well!

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: I get the error in the rails server "ControllerName::SnippetHighlighter is undefined" but, according to the asciicasts, I should not see that error in the rails server but instead in the resque-web! The background job should be handled by the redis server not rails server, isn't it?

Comment: Did you launch your resque worker?

Comment: yes by doing `rake resque:work QUEUE='*'`.

Comment: @SadikshaGautam So us your full code where are actually calling the resque

Answer (score 0):

The railscasts you are following uses [rails 3.0.9](https://github.com/railscasts/271-resque/blob/master/coderbits-after/Gemfile.lock#L50) and [resque 1.17.1](https://github.com/railscasts/271-resque/blob/master/coderbits-after/Gemfile.lock#L69).

I suggest you to either bump up rails version or use lower version of resque which is compatible with rails 2.3.8 as it certainly seems to be an incompatibility issue.

Comment: no, its not compatibility issue, if it were, my rails server would not start, but give me error. When I used `resque 1.17.1` it had some dependency conflicts. But, I have solved the issue now, there was some tweaking to be done in resque.rb file.